# Using kwargs in functions

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am trying to use kwargs in this way:

```
def calculator(**optional_values):
    if optional_value.get('maximum'):
       number = 15*value
    if optional_value.get('minimum):
       number = 5*value
```

so if i run the following:

```
   calculator(maximum=5)
it would do: 15*5
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this. Any pointers would be very helpful

Comment: "get" returns a result. First store it in "value" and if "value" isn't "None" use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code for what you want to do :

```
def calculator(**optional_values):
    if 'maximum' in optional_values:
        return 15*optional_values.get("maximum")
    if 'minimum' in optional_values:
        return 5*optional_values.get("minimum")

print(calculator(maximum=5))
```

this outputs : `75` which is `15*5` as you wanted.